# Why jquery .remove doesnt work in my case

Tags: jquery

I am kinda confused. I want to remove option with x value from my select.

this code doesnt work:

```
$('.custom-select').each(function(i, obj) {
   let removableOption = $(this).find('option[value="remove"]');
   $(removableOption).remove();
   //removableOption.remove();
});
```

but for example this:

```
$('option[value="remove"]').remove();
```

works good, any explanation?

EDIT: my html code:

```
<select class="custom-select">
    <option value="remove">placeholder</option>
    <option value="1">a</option>
    <option value="2">b</option>
</select>`
```

Comment: Please can you post your HTML code? It's probably to do with your option not being a child of your `.custom-select` class

Comment: why not `removableOption.remove();`

Comment: Hej i just added html code,

Comment: i think your code working well.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/r7tL9h45/6/ your code is working fine

Comment: can you try one line $('.custom-select option[value="remove"]').remove();